# get_post_meta with variable

Tags: php, post-meta

I’ve created a custom post type and a corresponding meta box for a site I’m developing. As there are several entries for similar 'products', some of the post metas repeat, albeit with a trailing letter to distinguish them one from the other.

I’d like to know if there’s a way to call a post type by name while also incorporating a variable the end of the post_meta name so that it’s no longer necessary to list them all, but one to cover my bases.

Here’s what I refer to: `trmet_tour_status_a`, `trmet_tour_status_b`, `trmet_tour_status_c` and so forth are all custom fields which I need to display if they exist (there are at least seven of them). Is there a way I can use jQuery or a PHP function to change the trailing letter so I only need to write the code once?

```
<ul id="dateList">
<?php $dates_a = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trmet_tourdate_a', true); ?>
<?php if ( ! empty ( $dates_a ) ) { // if it exists, show... ?>
<li>
    <div class="tourDate"><?php echo $dates_a; ?></div>
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trmet_toururl_a', true); ?>" target="_blank" class="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trmet_tour_status_a', true); ?>"></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

In this code, I need to have it read so that it also looks for `_b`, `_c`, `_d` and all the way to j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's `range` to iterate through letters.

```
foreach( range('a', 'j') as $letter ) {
    if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'trmet_tour_status_' . $letter, true) ){
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'trmet_tour_status_' . $letter, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used a variation of this for my needs. I’ve never used the `range` function, and am glad to know it exists. Thanks again!